# How to add resource bundle into a xcode project using cmake?

Tags: xcode, cmake, bundle

I am trying to add a resource bundle into a generated xcode project with cmake. However I am having trouble getting this out. This is what i have so far?

```
set(MACOSX_BUNDLE_RESOURCES "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/resource.bundle")
set_source_files_properties(MACOSX_BUNDLE_RESOURCES PROPERTIES MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION Resources)
add_executable(project MACOSX_BUNDLE ${FILES_SRC} ${FILES_RSC})
```

It seems it doesn't see resource.bundle package at all. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems I found a solution:

```
file(GLOB FILES_RSC "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/resource.bundle")
set_source_files_properties(${FILES_RSC} PROPERTIES MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION Resources)
```